# gvim copy a string, and want to paste to multiple lines in block style

Tags: vim

I have something like

```
longStrPattern....
Line0
xx...
LineN
```

What I want to have is

```
longStrPattern....
longStrPattern Line0
longStrPattern xx...
longStrPattern LineN
```

I know one way to do this is to block select Line0 to LineN and do insert by typing longStrPattern and then escape key.
Is there a better way that I don't need to type manually longStrPattern as it could be quite a long string.

Comment: You're also adding a space to all lines but the first... What about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can leverage the power of vim macros.
We can do the following:

1. Yank the long String `yt.`
2. Go to next line `j`
3. Start recording the macro `qa`
4. Go to start of the line `0`
5. Paste the yanked text to the front `P`
6. Enter insert mode and  add a space `i <esc>`
7. Go to the next line `j`
8. Finish recording `q`
9. Replay the macro by typing `2@a` where `2` is the number of lines to play the macro on

Comment: step 9 `2@q` should be `2@a` following vim's macro usage.

Comment: yes edited the answer. Made a mistake in typing 

Answer (score 1):

Given your example is just an example, I will ignore the fact that you're adding a space to lines from 2nd to last which is not in the first. With the cursor at the beginning of the first line, try this:

1. <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> or whatever you need to *delete* the text that you want to be in front of all lines
2. <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd><kbd>G</kbd><kbd>P</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>, where

   - <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> visually selects the first column
   - <kbd>P</kbd> *puts what you deleted in step 1 in place of the first column (i.e. it **deletes the first column** you've just selected)*
   - <kbd>p</kbd> puts back the column you've just deleted.

Doing so with your input file gives

```
longStrPattern....
longStrPatternLine0
longStrPatternxx...
longStrPatternLineN
```

In case your input was (see the space after `longStrPattern`)

```
longStrPattern ....
Line0
xx...
LineN
```

you could do <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd><space></kbd><kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd><kbd>G</kbd><kbd>P</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> to get

```
longStrPattern ....
longStrPattern Line0
longStrPattern xx...
longStrPattern LineN
```

Comment: I have tried the method1. Can I check for 'dt.' in step1, 'd' is for delete. '.' is to repeat previous command. Then what is 't' for? Thanks!

Comment: `t` is _till before_. See `:help t` for details. And simply try it out and see what it does.

Comment: Yes, I have tried before I ask again. I just realized I have made some mistake earlier. In fact, simply VISUAL select and delete, and do a block paste will do. Earlier I always do VISUAL BLOCK select and delete, which is not correct. Now it is fixed. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you copy 'longStrPattern' try using this:

```
:2,$s/.*/\=@0 . ' ' . submatch(0)
```